# ADO.NET is missing even after the installation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I've just installed the ADO.NET entity but I'm still missing the model in New Project. I made a research around the web and I found several solutions that didn't help me a lot. I tried to reinstall the Entity Framework, to add (in my case update) the assemblies from the project, to install the  "EFTools.msi" from "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache". Any ideas what's going on? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 from DreamSpark.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The entity Framework Model is a file item, not a project. So create a Class Library first and then in the class library use the <kbd>Add new item..</kbd> to add your ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Model:

[image]

Comment: I used to try on both new project and in ASP.NET MVC -> Add new item and it's missing again.

Comment: try running `devenv /setup` to rebuild the templates. Please post a few more detailed screenshots of what you are doing, as it's impossible to give you a better answer without seeing more of your solution. Any chance you installed a version of EFTools for the wrong version of Visual Studio? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762