# ADO.NET missing in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm using [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) 2019 and I'm trying to get "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" working there.  [This M$ community post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15bf0a01-f9ce-4cff-9a60-3097170cffd3/adonet-entity-data-model-template-is-missing-in-vs-2019-community-need-help?forum=adodotnetentityframework) suggests creating a project with the mention ".NET Framework".  The animated screenshot below shows that I did follow the advice but that didn't work.

[image: created .NET Framework project]

[ADO.NET is missing even after the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29048153/3184351) suggests installing EF6.  I did that a long time ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled VS 2019 & I switched back to VS 2017.  It works as expected.

[image: entity-relation digram]

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is install the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) nuget package in your project, and you're good to go. No need for Entity Framework if you don't want to use it.

Comment: You're missing the question.  I'm trying to follow a tutorial using EF Database First like https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 you just did not formulate your question correctly. I suggest you edit your question appropriately so that you can get the answer you actually need.

Comment: I've [edit]ed my question.  Hope that would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue and found it is due to my project is .NET Core.

So, I recreate a new project in .NET Framework then the ADO item will show up.

[image]